# Safe multiplication of two 64-bit signed integers

Tags: c, integer

The function below implements safe multiplication of two 64-bit signed integers, preventing overflow from occurring:

```
// Multiplies two 64-bit signed ints if possible.
// Returns 0 on success, and puts the product of x and y into the result.
// Returns 1 if there was an overflow.
int int64_mult(int64_t x, int64_t y, int64_t * result)
{
    *result = 0;
    if (x > 0 && y > 0 && x > INT64_MAX / y) return 1;
    if (x < 0 && y > 0 && x < INT64_MIN / y) return 1;
    if (x > 0 && y < 0 && y < INT64_MIN / x) return 1;
    if (x < 0 && y < 0 && (x <= INT64_MIN || y <= INT64_MIN || -x > INT64_MAX / -y))
        return 1;
    *result = x * y;
    return 0;
}
```

Did I get the logic for detecting overflows right?  I am most interested in making sure that no undefined behavior will occur, and that the function will always return the right results.

We can assume that `int64_t` will be a two's complement integer, because this is for GCC and GCC does not support any other type of integer.

For the convenience of the code reviewers (you), I made a complete, self-contained test suite that you can just run in your favorite C/C++ environment:

https://gist.github.com/DavidEGrayson/06cf7ea73f82a05490ba

I am not too interested in code style issues.  I am aware it might be nice to assert that the output pointer is not null, and it might be nice to add braces and parentheses.  But really I want to know if the code is actually correct.

I am somewhat interested in making the code simpler if you have a way to do that; maybe some of the cases could be combined.

I am also aware that the logic might be easier if I just used a 128-bit integer to store the multiplication result, but I would like to get it right without doing that.

The reason I am asking this is because I am working on adding [intsafe.h](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff521693) to mingw-w64 (a GCC compiler for Windows), so I am implementing safe multiplication of signed and unsigned numbers.  This function is analogous to [`LongLongMult`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh707047) in intsafe.h.  Your contribution will help make this header safer.  You can see my progress [here](https://github.com/DavidEGrayson/intsafe).

Comment: What about when `y == 0`? Shouldn't that return some sort of error, too?

Comment: No, multiplying a number by zero is fine, and always yields a result of zero.

Comment: Ah, I was looking at the division within the condition, but in all cases you have 'y < 0' or 'y > 0' first, so yeah, no problem. Guess I was tired when I first looked at it!

Comment: [How to detect integer overflow in C/C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/199333/995714), [detecting multiplication of uint64_t integers overflow with C](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8534107/995714), [multiplication of large numbers, how to catch overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1815367/995714), [How do I detect overflow while multiplying two 2's complement integers?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2713972/995714)

Comment: You should check `result` for a null pointer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Given that you are writing for gcc, is there a reason you're not using the [builtins](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Integer-Overflow-Builtins.html)?

```
bool __builtin_add_overflow (type1 a, type2 b, type3 *res)
bool __builtin_sub_overflow (type1 a, type2 b, type3 *res)
bool __builtin_mul_overflow (type1 a, type2 b, type3 *res)
```

But as to your question, it looks correct to me, modulo the answer by the other poster.

Comment: FYI for anyone else reading this, these built-ins were added in GCC 5, which came out fairly recently.

Comment: All 253 functions in intsafe.h can be implemented using these built-ins, wow!  Casting from one integer type to another can be done with `__builtin_add_overflow(a, 0, res)`.

Answer (score 8):

I believe your logic is correct: all combinations of positive and negative `x` and `y` are checked.

You can replace the last condition with the obvious, more natural and simple:

```
if (x < 0 && y < 0 && x < INT64_MAX / y) return 1;
```

Comment: Thanks, your change does indeed seem to work, and all the tests still pass.

Answer (score 5):

There are [multiple ways to fix C up for using a `bool` type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1921539/2792531).  And using a `bool` type helps make our code more human-readable, so we should [*certainly* be doing that](http://importblogkit.com/2015/03/writing-readable-code/).

---

There are no braces.  "Optional" doesn't mean you should omit whenever possible.  "Optional" means for some reason,  the compiler will manage to compile even without the braces.  It's two extra characters and it ensures that if anyone ever does get in here and modify this otherwise simple method, they have no chances of screwing it up.

---

You have appropriately documented the return values:

> ```
> // Returns 0 on success, and puts the product of x and y into the result.
> // Returns 1 if there was an overflow.
> ```

But I think you're returning the opposite of what you should.

Looking at this method, I want to use it something like this...

```
if(int64_mult(a, b, &c)) {
    // use c
} else {
    // there was an overflow
}
```

But I can't because you return `0` on success and non-zero on failure.  This is what we expect from *programs*, but not what we expect from *functions*.  I think this should be fixed.

---

> ```
> *result = 0;
> ```

I don't write enough C to know if this would be the expected behavior or not.  I think I would not want this to happen however.

If this function automatically sets our passed in value to 0 or the actual multiplied value, it's only *barely* more useful than not checking at all.

I think I would prefer the `result` variable not being set to anything at all if it would overflow.  Just leave me with whatever my variable was before, and the return from the function tells me it didn't actually multiply.

---

The function's name leaves a lot to be desired.  I don't think `int64` is fully required here, as the function arguments declare the type.  I'm not sure what we've gained by abbreviating `multiply` except leaving ourselves with the *potential* for possible confusion if we need some other similarly named sort of function (`multiples` perhaps?).  And the name leave no indication that it's at all special versus just doing `a * b`.

Comments are great, and you've done that.  But [self-documenting code](http://importblogkit.com/2015/03/writing-readable-code/) is better.  Let's call this method something better.  How about:

```
bool safe_overflow_multiply(int64_t a, int64_t b, int64_t *result);
```

Comment: I appreciate your taking the time to write all this up.  However: I mentioned braces in the question.  Since I am actually implementing a [function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh707047) in a header defined by Microsoft, I have no choice about the return value and function name.  Setting the result to zero (or something) is important, since it could potentially save users from the undefined behavior of reading an uninitialized variable.  Undefined behavior can cause [security check elimination](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=30475)

Comment: C isn't C++. There's no parameter-type overloading. If someone wanted to write one of these for `int16_t` they wouldn't be able to.